# H2 Database - how to protect a column?

Tags: h2

From a previous H2 question here: [How to create a secured field in H2 database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770242/how-to-create-a-secured-field-in-h2-database)

I gather that I need to put `cipher aes` to make a field encrypted. But that does not work.

The statement:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyTable(
    myPK varchar(256),
    protectedField blob cipher aes
    ...
);
```

returns:

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyTable(
>           myPK varchar(256),
>           protectedField blob cipher[*] aes
>           ...
>       );"; expected "(, FOR, UNSIGNED, INVISIBLE, VISIBLE, NOT, NULL, AS, DEFAULT, GENERATED, ON, NOT, NULL, AUTO_INCREMENT, BIGSERIAL, SERIAL, IDENTITY, NULL_TO_DEFAULT, SEQUENCE, SELECTIVITY, COMMENT, CONSTRAINT, PRIMARY, UNIQUE, NOT, NULL, CHECK, REFERENCES, ,, )"

So, how do I make a column encrypted by H2?